# Load JavaScript when partial is called via ColorBox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, colorbox

It seems when loading a Razor partial view via ColorBox (not using an iframe), the JavaScript libraries do not initialize properly or it is an artifacte of the partial. If I include the libraries in the parent page, the JavaScript function runs inside the partial jsut fine. I don't see any errors coming from the browser when the library is in the partial, but it is not working. If I move the library (in this case `fileuploader.js`) outside of the partial and keep the function in the partial it works fine.

Example:

```
<script src="@Url.ContentArea("~/Scripts/plugins/ajaxUpload/fileuploader.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

                   <div id="file-uploader">
                        <noscript>
                            <p>
                                Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
                        </noscript>
                    </div>


<script>

 $(function () {
        var fileCount = 0;
        var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
            action: '/Admin/Avatar/AvatarUpload',
            debug: true,
            params: {
                'userId': '@ViewBag.UserId'
            },
            onSubmit: function (id, fileName) {
                fileCount++;
            },
            onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJson) {
                if (responseJson.success) {
                    if (createAvatar(responseJson.file, responseJson.imageId)) {
                        fileCount--;

                    } else {
                        fileCount--;

                    }
                } else {
                    $("span.qq-upload-file:contains(" + fileName + ")").text(responseJson.errorMessage);
                    fileCount--;
                }

                if (fileCount == 0) {
                 .....
                }

            },
            onCancel: function (id, fileName) {
                fileCount--;
                if (fileCount == 0) {
                    ....
                }
            }
        });
    });

<script>
```

Comment: It's a 404 error? Are you really running into an Area? I say this because of `@Url.ContentArea`, if you try with `@Url.Content`, what happened?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check whether there are duplicate references to the JavaScript libraries you are using (one in the parent and one in the partial).

This is a common issue and it will not raise any errors whatsoever, but will stop your JavaScript code from executing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a time line problem.Before the "Partial View" load(or appending the div) JavaScript try to bind it and fail.So it cannot find a element which is in your Partial View document.I had a problem with like this with "ColorBox".I have found a solution for this problem.For example : When you call GET or POST method ,after the query put a control point like this .For example for binding "colorbox" :

```
function getMyPartial(partialname) {
    var resultDiv = document.getElementById("content");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: partialname,                                                                                 
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            resultDiv.innerHTML = "";
            resultDiv.innerHTML = data.toString();
        }
    });    
    var indd = 0; //This is Control Point
    if (partialname == "YourPartialName") {
        var yourelementinpartial= document.getElementById("example");
        while (!yourelementinpartial) {
            indd++;
        }  
        $(".group4").colorbox({ rel: 'group4' }); //binding point
    }      
}
```

At the control point, if any of the element in your PartialView document has found it will bind.